# How to pass parameters in react functions with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function

Here is the structure of my folder:

```
 src--|

 |--ComponentsFolder1--Button.tsx

 |--ComponentsFolder2--ParentDiv.tsx
```

My problem is as follows:
Button.tsx is a react component which calls a fetch function located in react ParentDiv.tsx with a few parameters:

```
type getNewVerseProps = {
   getNewVerseFunc: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => string;
};

const Button = ({ getNewVerseFunc }: getNewVerseProps) => {
   return (
      <div>
               <div
                  onClick={getNewVerseFunc.bind(name, id)}>
               </div>
      </div>
```

Now, as you can see, I want to call the function on my ParentDiv.tsx file with the specified parameters in Button.tsx:

```
    const getNewVerseFunc = async (name: string, id: string) => {
      const requ = await fetch(
         `https://api.scripture.api.bible/${name}/${id}`,
         {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
               "api-key": bibleApi,
            },
         }
   };

<Button getNewVerseFunc={getNewVerseFunc}/>
```

My problem is that the params in the function are not being passed down in the Button component when i call the getNewVerseFunc function in the ParentDiv component

Answer (score 4):

First of all you've used `bind` wrongly. First argument is a context, which is in this case ignored, because you have an arrow function, which is instantly bound; but it is impossible to rebind  bound function.

Common practice is to have button with `onClick` callback, like:

```
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

type Props = {
  onClick: MouseEventHandler;
}

const Button: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ onClick, children }) => (
    <div onClick={onClick}>
        {children}
    </div>
);
```

And for simplicity avoid using `bind`, `call` or `apply` if possible; it's good that you are aware of these functions, but using them usually reduces readability.

Then in parent you can do the following:

```
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

const ParentDiv: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const name = 'Some name';
    const id = 'Some id';

    return (
        <Button onClick={() => getNewVerseFunc(name, id)}>
            Click me
        </Button>
    );
};
```

---

If your Button component is wrapped with `memo`, then it makes sense to use `useCallback` hook for onClick handler, but that's already micro optimisation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it really helped! I appreciate it!

Comment: @D.R. You should consider accepting this answer to your question if it helped.

Comment: I think you forgot = in 
type Props = {
  onClick: MouseEventHandler;
}